# nodejs - mongo error: unable to create database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having problem connecting to creating database for nodejs , i have installed mongo db successfully, but couldn't create database, giving below error:

```
 D:\nodejs>node demo_create_mongo_db.js
    
    D:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
              throw err
              ^
    MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Mong
    oError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
        at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\serv
    er.js:336:35)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connectio
    n\pool.js:280:12)
        at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\co
    nnection.js:187:49)
        at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

i am using this code to create database:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;  
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/MongoDatabase";  
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {  
if (err) throw err;  
console.log("Database created!");  
db.close();  
});
```

Comment: Check if mongod is running: `service mongod status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing and writing this answer , you have installed mongodb but your server at localhost is not yet running .

Try :

> ```
> mongod.exe --dbpath c:\data\db
> ```

and then run your node.js (your code looks perfectly fine )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it is working fine , when i install and start mango db server and its services.